# Book: Modern day equivalent of the Wrox Spring book

Tags: java, spring

I loved the 2005 book "Professional Java Development with the Spring Framework" by Johnson.  What would be the 2008-9 equivalent of this in terms of the quality and clarity the book provided?

Essentially looking for a book for someone new to Spring, I still think the 2005 book is somewhat relevant, but much has changed in the Spring world since then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best of the bunch today seems to be the "Pro Spring" series, and the "Spring an Action" series. I can particularly recommend the former.

edit: It seems that Pro Spring covers Spring 2.5, but Spring in Action is still stuck back in the 2.0 days

Comment: Now the question becomes... Can I forgive Apress after that *horrible* Hibernate book they put out?  I can't even remember what it was called. I literally wanted to vomit after attempting to read it, the authors literally just copied the free Hibernate documentation from the site and put it in a book along with a bunch of API.

Answer (score 2):

I'm reading ["Spring Recipes"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599799) right now (~1/3rd of the way done), and I can recommend it.  Spring 3.0 isn't out yet, so it's right up to date covering 2.5.

UPDATE: Finished it this week.  I can highly recommend it, just for the chapter on Spring Security alone.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your time scales, you may want to wait until Spring 3.0 is out (I believe it's imminent since [3.0 M3 is out](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/06/spring-framework-30-m3-released/)). Looks like Apress has an [appropriate book](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430218456).

Comment: Actually, M3 is out, and has been for some time, but RC1 is very late, and I'm getting twitchy.

Comment: Ah. Thx for that. Will edit appropriately

Comment: It seems hasty to release a Spring 3 book before the RC builds are released... it ain't feature-complete yet.

Comment: Well, yes. I would prefer to buy a book once it's been out and been shaken down for some time to find the annoyances/glitches etc. I expected OReilly to have a Spring book, but they're remarkably bare on this topic