# How to integrate Spring to a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse with JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have looked everywhere and I have not found a site that can show how can I integrate Spring to my  Web Dynamic JSP project built in Eclipse. All the references I have found, they are outdated or are using the new Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, which by default does not recognize JSP.

I am pretty sure, that this question may be sound silly for many Spring Programmer rock stars, but for me it is kind of BIG pain.

Can some one, please direct me to a web site, or book where I can integrate Spring? The real reason is because I want to integrate Spring Security.

Comment: [Book: Modern day equivalent of the Wrox Spring book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1155374/573032)

Comment: I just found out that those books only talk about Thymeleaf. That means that JSP is dead?

Answer (score 0):

After reading bunch of forums, books reviews and talking with some Spring veterans who migrated from standards JSP EE portal to the new Spring MVC. Here the Top 2 books I found indispensable for anyone who wants to port current JSP projects into Spring.

1. Spring MVC: Beginner's Guide (http://amzn.to/1PRoFS8)

2.- Mastering Spring MVC 4 (http://amzn.to/1Qc4UXG)